# searching the ObservableCollection list based on a string given in search bar

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on **Xamarin** forms project.

Below is my template .xaml file:

```
<StackLayout>
<SearchBar>.....</SearchBar>
<ListView>.....</ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I'm populating listview as:

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Ticket>> TicketList
    {
        get { return _ticketList; }
        set { _ticketList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

listview.ItemSource = TicketList;
```

Here is the search code:

```
public void FilterList(string searchText)
{
TicketListNew = // getting list from local database

 // searching each field of list with the text entered
  GroupCollections(TicketListNew.Where(Tl => Tl.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())
}

private void GroupCollections(List<Ticket> ticketListNew){
var sorted = from ticket in ticketListNew
                     orderby ticket.DelPUDate
                     group ticket by GetTicketDate(ticket.DelPUDate) into ticketListGroup
                     select new Grouping<string, Ticket>(ticketListGroup.Key, ticketListGroup);
        if (TicketList == null) TicketList = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Ticket>>(sorted);
        else
        {
            TicketList.Clear();
            var temp = sorted.ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
            {
                TicketList.Add(temp[i]);
            }
        }

}
```

During the searching, it goes to the else part, and here it is taking too long to populate the list to TicketList. I feel like this is not the right design to clear the list first and assign each list item once at a time.

any better solution to search?

Comment: Can you give an indication as to about how many items are in your list?

Comment: Anyway imo the problem is indeed in the clear and rebuilding the list. It's an observable collection that's attached to a listview meaning everytime you clear the list it has to remove all the visual elements from your page and then add them again (even if you recycle them), this makes clearing and rebuilding the list a very costly operation. Probably better to check which items you have to remove and remove only those from the list. Secondly doing a database call every time FilterList is called is also a bad idea, just store an in memory copy and do your logic on that

Answer (score 1):

I'd bind the `ItemsSource` property on the `ListView` instead of assigning it and also make sure you are setting [RecycleElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#recycleelement) in your `ListView`, so that your items gets recycled (if you do not put this all of the items will be loaded in the `ListView` directly; setting this will enable the virtualization of the items so that the cells are recycled and therefore the performance is improved dramatically for large collections)

```
<ListView
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding TicketList}`>
    ...
    <x:Arguments>
        <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
    </x:Arguments>
</ListView>
```

And also directly do a foreach of your `sorted` variable:

```
foreach(var item in sorted)
{
    TicketList.Add(item);
}
```

If you do a `.ToList()` it will generate and allocate you a new `List` object, by doing the foreach directly will take the `IEnumerable` and iterate through it by reference.

I think this will speeds up the process.

HIH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using customListView so i cannot use the above caching strategy, instead I'm already setting CachingStrategy = "RecycleElement" to my list view. Also now Im binding the itemsource in xaml and doing foreach to sorted. But i still see some lag.

Comment: I'd have to see your `DataTemplate` of your item to help you out. Surely your items are too heavy to be rendered or you're doing to much layout nesting with will certainly reduce the performance. 
By the way the lag is between inserting each item or is it until it loads the first one / all of them?

Comment: lag is because of inserting each item (for loop), based on my debugging

Comment: also my my DataTemplate is big, Each list item has 8 rows and are grouped by date.

Comment: i just added some logs to see what is causing this lag. I can clearly see for loop is taking lot of time

Comment: If I were you I'd comment some of the rows or controls in your item to see if the lag goes away

Comment: yeah i just did that. What i see is If the list items are less, then search is fast, if the list items are above 200, then there is a log

Comment: Are you sure you are setting `RecycleElement`? If that is set the amount of items in the list shouldn't affect the rendering

Comment: Yes.             <ListView x:Name="lvTickets" ItemsSource="{Binding TicketList}" Grid.Row="1" ItemTapped="lvTickets_ItemTapped" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Gray" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True">

Comment: Check everything in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#improving-listview-performance maybe it can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184898/discussion-between-sai-and-fmaccaroni).